# Where to put responsibility in Domain Model?

Tags: model, dns

I am creating domain model. I have Goal ( something that user wants to achieve in his entire year) concept/object and it has status that will vary over time. Now, User will update his status. Where should I put the responsibility of creating, updating and deleting the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be looking to use the [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) to keep the database responsibility out of your domain model.  This is known as "Persistence Ignorance."